# Can't set cookie in ASP.NET 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, razor

I have been trying to set cookies for a users login info, but I keep getting these errors.

I am importing all of these

```
using System;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

// IDE says these are all unnessary
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
```

The code is this:

```
string token = Auth.password(username,password);

HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("token",token);
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

And here are the errors

```
C:\xxx\my-server\Pages\Login.cshtml.cs(30,5): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpCookie' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\xxx\my-server\my-server.csproj]
C:\xxx\my-server\Pages\Login.cshtml.cs(30,29): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpCookie' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\xxx\my-server\my-server.csproj]
C:\xxx\my-server\Pages\Login.cshtml.cs(32,22): error CS1061: 'IResponseCookies' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no accessible extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'IResponseCookies' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\xxx\my-server\my-server.csproj]
```

I created the project using the command `dotnet new razor`.
I am using vscode.
The dotnet version is 5.0.301.

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iresponsecookies?view=aspnetcore-5.0, `IResponseCookies` is in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` namespace.

Comment: @user9938 I was already using `System.Web`, and adding `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` didn't change anything

Comment: System.Web is no longer a thing in ASP.NET Core. System.Web is the old ASP.NET Framework.

Comment: @mason Then how should I do this?

Comment: httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("token", token, new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30) }); This needs to inject IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor.

Comment: @GuyatMercator Thanks so much! It is finally working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was solved by changing the code to:

```
string token = Auth.password(username,password);

HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("token", token, 
    new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30) });
```